# Getting error when looping audio_service Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I get an error when I click the repeat button in my Flutter app.

Error-

> Unhandled Exception: Bad state: You cannot add items while items are being added from addStream

code.

```
IconButton(
 onPressed: () {
  audioHandler.setRepeatMode(AudioServiceRepeatMode.one);},
 icon: Icon(
  Icons.repeat_one_on_rounded,
  color: thirdColor,size: 36,),),
```